# Creating additonal step on jquery step by step form

Tags: jquery

I've been using the following jquery template as a step by step form for my current work. Was just wondering how I could add an extra step or two because right now it only gives me three steps.

A working demonstration can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/5/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an example with one step more:

http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/8/

You have to add:

HTML

```
<div id="third-step">
    <h2>Third Step</h2>
    <div class="label"><label for="Site">Site</label></div>
            What you want...
</div>
```

JS

```
    ....
    else if( whichStep == 'second-step' )
                    {
                        // validate second-step
                    }
//this -->
                    else if( whichStep == 'third-step' )
                    {
                        // validate third-step
                    }
//this -->
                    else if( whichStep == 'last-step' )
                    {
                        // validate last-step
                    }
    ....
```

and the same for each step you want

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/9/

Just add another div at the same level as `#first-step` (for example `<div id="third-step">`) and add the validation block in JavaScript:

```
else if( whichStep == 'third-step' ) {
    // validate third-step
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this:

```
   <div id="third-step">
        <h2>Third Step</h2>
        <div class="label"><label for="Site">Site</label></div>

    *stuff*

    </div> <!-- end third-step -->
```

After the second and before the last step.

In the javascript do the same with:

```
else if( whichStep == 'third-step' )
                {
                    // validate third-step
                }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/10/